How to do a commit from digitalOcean periodically for saving data during the deployment into my django project
I have deploy a django project on digital ocean, the project mainly save documents like xlsx and csv, but while the web app is deploy users send documents to the platform, my question is how could I keep those documents saved aside of downloading one by one from the the admin panel of Django, or how could be the approach for dealing with that?
I was thinking in creating a template for downloading all the data with one click, and then do a commit to the repository with that data that I downloaded previously, and digital ocean would take all the repository and make a redeploy, but the main dificulty woulb be that If I do that, I would need to do that manually

This question aims towards the MEDIA_ROOT variable which you can set in your settings.py file. Here you should tell django where to persistently store the media files, meaning all content coming from users. Your goal would be to set it up in a way that your project (your code base) can be updated easily while the database and media files keep being untouched. In a microservice setup (e.g. docker) MEDIA_ROOT would point to a persistent volume. I never worked with digitalOcean, therefore this is just a comment - hope it helps anyways.

Well seems like you should separate file upload from the django app. That way people can still upload files while they django app is down or is being updated. You could store these files in a pending folder and when the app is up then it periodically checks the pending folder and processes any file found.
